# SQL attribute (column) value contstraint

Tags: sql, sqlite, constraints

I'm using sqlite as my database. I need a attribute to be limited to values of 0 or 1.

Is it possible to specify this in the definition of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable
( id INT Primary key
, onefield INT CHECK(onefield IN (0,1))  ---the limited field/attribute
)
```